# How to serialize and deserialize objects with cbor2?

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, cbor

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize object using cbor2 but even after following the documentation I cannot properly do it. Let' suppose I have the following two classes:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5
        self.b = set()

    def a(self):
        return self.a

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a

    def a(self):
        return a

a = A()
b = B(a)
```

Can anyone show me how to do it for the object `a` please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a late answer.

CBOR2 is currently missing support for serializing sets which could be stored as tagged arrays.

There is a ticket for adding support here:

https://github.com/agronholm/cbor2/issues/14